# SFINAE with enable_if and overloading

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, enable-if

I've done some looking around, but was unable to find a solution to my specific problem.

I have the code:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value || std::is_enum<T>::value, std::string>::type
    convertToString(const T argument) { return std::to_string(argument); }

std::string convertToString(std::string string);
```

What the code is supposed to do: Use the template version for any numeric type (int, float, double and also ENum) and use the std::string version for anything else.

The code itself compiles fine, however when I pass the function a class, which has a `operator const char *` overload (which is a viable constructor for `std::string`), it throws me the following bulk of messages:

```
no matching function for call to 'SQL_Connection::convertToString(ClassName &)’

candidate: template<class T> typename std::enable_if<(std::is_arithmetic<_Tp>::value || std::is_enum<_Tp>::value), std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::type convertToString(T)
 convertToString(const T argument) { return std::to_string(argument); }
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In substitution of ‘template<class T> typename std::enable_if<(std::is_arithmetic<_Tp>::value || std::is_enum<_Tp>::value), std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::type convertToString(T) [with T = ClassName]’:
```

I've been trying to wrap my head around `enable_if` and what it does, but at this point I find myself stumped.

Why isn't it falling back to the `std::string` overload, when it clearly is neither arithmetic nor an ENum?

If I explicitly convert the object to string or const char *, it works as expected.

Thank you very much for your help.

Additional info: I'm using C++11 and g++ 7.3.0 on an Ubuntu system.

Comment: Fwiw, msvc 19.00.24215.1 (vs2015) complains in the exact opposite resolution. "error C2664: 'std::string convertToString(std::string)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'ClassName' to 'std::string'"

Comment: It looks like T is being deduced as char*, which is matching in preference to the non-template overload. What if you add a const char* non-template overload?

Comment: @IanGralinski Unfortunately this doesn't change a thing.
The interesting thing is, that it does work, if I perform the conversion manually. (As in: c_str() (returning const char *) or toString (returning std::string)).

A cast however yields a different error: no matching function for call to convertToString(const char *&)...

Comment: @RefugnicEternium Even if you remove the template version, the code does not compile, so I think you're asking the wrong question :)

Comment: @IanGralinski On days like these, I feel stupid.
I mistyped the function prototype (or much rather I forgot to remove something from a previous attempt), which is why your suggestion didn't work for me.

It does help and Quimby was so kind to tell me why that is.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your usage of `enable_if` is correct and the problem is not in the function template at all. The thing is that the following won't compile either:

```
std::string convertToString(std::string string);
struct Foo{
    operator const char*(){...}
};
Foo foo; 
converToString(foo);
```

The reason is that the compiler is only allowed to do 1 user-defined conversion per passed parameter to match function arguments. In this case it would have to do 2 - `Foo->const char*` and `const char*->std::string`.

Comment: *Argh*, and to think I spent hours trying to figure out what the heck I was doing wrong!

I completely missed that 'must not convert more than once' thing.
I ended up implementing an inline overload for `const char *` (like @IanGralinski suggested), which does the second conversion silently.

Thank you so much. :)

Comment: @RefugnicEternium Yea, stuff happens...The error message is a bit misleading, it shows candidates and `std converToString(str)` is rightly not among them but that's not what usually a person notices when looking at the error.

Comment: @Quimby `convertToString` is a candidate (not a viable one though), and is actually present in the error message of `gcc`, `clang` and `msvc`. OP simply cut the message a bit too early.

Comment: @Holt You are correct. After switching the definitions around, it placed the candidate on top and even told me that there was 'no known conversion from ClassType to std::string'...unfortunately I must have overlooked it entirely.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium If you have it at your disposal, you can try to switch your compiler to `clang` (I assume you're using `gcc`). `clang` often (not always) have more meaningful messages than `gcc`, e.g., in this case, the messages are quite short and explicit: https://godbolt.org/z/lcNQVj